# Passing Variable to SQL insert statement

Tags: sql

I know this code here selects columns from one table and inserts it into another table. However, I have a value that I want to insert into one of the columns, how do I pass in the value?

This selects from on table and inserts into another...

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

However, I want column1 to have a value that I set above the code e.g MY_NAME varchar(20)

**set @MY_NAME = "Helen"**

Then my insert statement to be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT *@MY_NAME*, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: @MalwareWerewolf I'm using SQL Server, sorry forgot to mention it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you should do something like this:

```
declare @MY_NAME AS varchar(20)
set @MY_NAME = 'Helen'

Insert into table2([column1], [column2], [column3]) 
select @MY_NAME, column2, column3  
from table1
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it in the morning, just leaving the office now. Will report back in the morning.

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm - exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: I’m glad that worked ;)